# Mean value for a simple random variable

Tags: probability, combinatorics

From a box with numbers from 1 to 90, 6 numbers are extracted without reintroduction. To play this "game", you have to pay 1 and you win 15 millions if you predict the 6 numbers (nothing in all the other cases). I have to compute the mean value $E(x)$ and I also have to determine what the prize should be in order the mean value to be $0$.

$E_1(x)=15\cdot10^6\cdot\frac{\binom{6}{6}\binom{84}{0}}{\binom{90}{6}}-1=-0.9$

$E_2(x)=y\cdot\frac{\binom{6}{6}\binom{84}{0}}{\binom{90}{6}}-1=0$,

and I compute $y$. Is this right?

Comment: You did not take into account the probability of losing (almost $1$ but not exactly).

Comment: ${90\choose 6}=622614630\approx60\cdot10^7$, so your arithmetic is awry.

Comment: But if I receive $0$ "in all other cases", the result does not change. Does it? @almagest I do not understand your comment.

Comment: Your terms are right. But the result of the first one is not right. $15\cdot 10^6\cdot\frac{\binom{6}{6}\cdot\binom{84}{0}}{\binom{90}{6}}-1\approx-0.976$

Comment: @drhab The probability of paying one monetary unit is $1$.

Comment: Ok thank you very much.

Comment: @callculus Yes, I see now and will delete my comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, most of this is right, but as noted in the comments, you miscalculated; the result in the first equation is approximately $-0.9759$. Also you didn't introduce $x$ and $y$, and random variables are conventionally denoted by capital letters.